# What is a Galois group $Gal( \Bbb Q(E[4])/ \Bbb Q)$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined by $E:y^2＝x^3-x$.
What is a Galois group $Gal( \Bbb Q(E[4])/ \Bbb Q)$ ?
we can easily find $E[2]＝\{(-1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0), \infty\}$ by finding a point at which tangent line intersects with $E$ at infinity.

But I cannot list up all points of $E[4]$.

Is this difficult to do by hand ?  I'm interested in what the Galois group, without listing all points of $E[4]$, are there method to find Galois group ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $E[4]$ here means $E(K^{alg})[4]$ and that is isomorphic to $Z/4Z×Z/4Z$ and it is not the same as $E[2]$. It consists of $16$ points.

Comment: Have you seen the duplication formula $$2P=\left(\frac{x^4-2Ax^2-8Bx+A^2}{4y^2}, \frac{x^6+5Ax^4+20Bx^3-5A^2x^2-4ABx-8B^2-A^3}{8y^3}  \right)?$$

Comment: Yes, but I need to calculate $6$ degree equation, it seems undoable by hand and find Galois group.

Comment: By the duplication formula, $P(x,y)$ is $4$-torsion and not $2$-torsion iff $x^6-5x^4-5x^2+1=0$ (because $A=-1,B=0$ here) ie iff $x^2$ is a root of $u^3-5u^2-5u+1=0$ ie $(u+1)(u^2-6u+1)=0$, so the $4$-torsion points are $(x,y)$ where $y^2=x^3-x$ and $x^2$ is $-1$ or $3 \pm 2\sqrt{2} = (1\pm \sqrt{2})^2$.